# Zoom in / Zoom out buttons not working by default in Oracle APEX charts?

Tags: oracle-apex

How can i enable the zoom in / zoom out buttons in a chart region to be enabled by default when the page loads? I noticed that if i zoom in / zoom out by holding ctrl and scrolling on the region / whole page then they become enabled...